# I am using red-black tree as a data structure. Is it better than std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl, tree

I would like to improve my code performance by replacing a red-black tree with any other data structure. I am having this red-black tree in memory, not on disk. Could you suggest other options which are faster than a red-black tree in terms of search, insertion and deletion?

Comment: Which is "better" depends very much on your use-cases.

Comment: a sorted std::vector or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx could be a choice

Comment: How big are your elements? how many do you have? How often do you have to search/insert. Do you need your data to be ordered? Where does your current implementation of tje rb tree come from

Comment: elements are large in number, more than a lac. searching and insertion are very frequent. ordering is there, but it can be ignored for the time being.

Comment: I would in addition suggest to watch Chandler Carruth "Efficiency with Algorithms, Performance with Data Structures" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use the RB tree for? If you need the objects you're storing to respect a sorting criterion, then your RB Trees are probably a better option. However, I suggest using STL's containers which are implemented using balanced BSTs **std::map** and **std::set**.

If you don't care about objects ordering, then use a HashTable. C++11 introduced **std::unordered_map** and **std::unordered_set** which have constant insert and look up time in average.

Comment: Is Hash table faster than rb tree if the ordering is not important? Doesn't Hast table have an inbuilt b-tree structure for searching? can i use B-tree instead of using rb-tree to get performance?

Comment: HashTable does not have anything to do with any kind of trees. It is another data structure.